# NetBeans jLable properties icon is not showing

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to add a background image to a JFrame form. I'm using a Jlabel to insert a background image, but when I click on the properties I can find the icon on that scroll list. What must I do?

Comment: i cant find the icon

Comment: Hi Richard, as I am reviewing your question it seems that your question could use either code that you have tried or images that depict your problem. This would also help improve the quality of your question and garner more attention from people who are willing to answer it. Also, you can edit your question rather than leaving comments.

Comment: thanks Cody, im new to this site and im still a student. ill fix my mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using the NetBeans Form Designer, click the three dots *next* to the dropdown, then select accordingly.

[image: screenshot of netbeans dialog]

You'll probably want to place the icon file into a folder inside `src/main/resources` so that it becomes a project resource. Then it will become available from the "File:" dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Tomas this helps me alot :)